# How to filter cell for string reoccurrences/duplicates?

Tags: google-sheets, split, concatenation, google-sheets-formula, textjoin

My sheet has a cell with content:

`Tomato, Potato, Beef, Tomato, Salmon, Beef`

I want to remove all reoccurring string elements of this cell so that the new cell shows this:

`Tomato, Potato, Beef, Salmon`

I've tried to achieve this with the `UNIQUE` and `TEXTJOIN` functions so far, without success. Is it possible to apply `FILTER` to a cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",true,UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(substitute(A1," ",),","))))
```

[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

or try:

```
=INDEX(TEXTJOIN(",", 1, UNIQUE(TRIM(FLATTEN(SPLIT(A1, ","))))
```

Answer (score 0):

This shorter one also works

```
=JOIN(", ",UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(A1,", "))))
```

[image]